# How to add 2 different classes to the same list?

Tags: c#

So I'm studying c# and I've come across the issue where I seem to be getting the error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Prog2Prov.Program+Order] when trying to print out the list and my code currently looks like this. I'm aware that there may be a lot of errors, however, I am still trying to grasp my hands around how c# works. Thanks for all the advice.

```
 List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

            bool close = true;
            while (close)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What type of order is this?(N=Normal/S=Special/#=End)");
                string parcel = Console.ReadLine();

                string name, location, date;
                int number;

                if (parcel == "N")
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the name of your order: ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter your order number: ");
                    number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter your order date: ");
                    date = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter your town: ");
                    location = Console.ReadLine();

                    orders.Add(new NormalOrder(name, number, date, location));

                }
                else if (parcel == "S")
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the name of your order: ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter your order number: ");
                    number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter your order date: ");
                    date = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Enter your country: ");
                    location = Console.ReadLine();

                    orders.Add(new NormalOrder(name, number, date, location));
                }
                else if (parcel == "#")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to see which countries or town your sent your parcel to?(C=Country/T=Town)");
                    string shipping = Console.ReadLine();
                    foreach(var order in orders)
                    if (shipping == "t")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(order);

                    }
                    else if (shipping == "C")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(order);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input, try again!");
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        class Order
        {
            protected string orderName { get; set; }
            protected int orderNumber { get; set; }
            protected string orderDate {get; set;}
        }       

        class NormalOrder : Order
        {
            private string town { get; set; }

            public NormalOrder(string orderName, int orderNumber, string orderDate, string town)
            {
                this.orderName = orderName;
                this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
                this.orderDate = orderDate;
                this.town = town;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Order name: " + orderName +"\nOrder number: " + orderNumber + "\nOrder date: " + orderDate + "\nOrder location:" + town.ToList();
            }
        }

        class SpecialOrder : Order
        {
            private string country;

            public SpecialOrder(string orderName, int orderNumber, string orderDate, string country)
            {
                this.orderName = orderName;
                this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
                this.orderDate = orderDate;
                this.country = country;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "Order name: " + orderName + "\nOrder number: " + orderNumber + "\nOrder date: " + orderDate + "\nOrder location:" + country.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?  Where is your `orders` declaration?

Comment: @LarsTech No line throws an error, the program is fully operable, however when I try to print the list at "Console.WriteLine(orders);" it prints what I entered in the question. I'm not quite sure what you mean as to orders declaration. Edit: My bad, just realized the list didn't get added, its at the top now!

Comment: What are you trying to fix? What are you expecting the output of that `Console.WriteLine` to be?

Comment: you should be doing a `foreach(var order in orders) Console.WriteLine(order)`

Comment: you can also override the `ToString()` method of order class to help with the display formatting unless you want to do it as part of Console.WriteLine

Comment: @zaggler you should mention that your solution requires addition of `using System.Linq;`

Comment: if you printout complex objects it will only show the Type as a string. (System.Collections.Generic.List because you have a List there). You will have to overwrite the toString() Method on order and then print out the order, not the list of orders
foreach(Order currentorder in orders) Console.WriteLine(currentorder)

Comment: @SuryaPratap Thanks! Your answer worked! I have edited the code to a point where it prints out correctly, however it prints both classes and I want to separate their printing.

Comment: If you have such a large body for your statement, you should put it in braces `{ }`. Else it's easy to make mistakes or get errors. C-like languages really need braces.

Comment: you can test `if (order is NormalOrder) { ... }`

Comment: @JHBonarius It still ends up printing the entire list even with that if statement. Edit: Nevermind, I'm stupid, it works. I was adding both inputs as NormalOrders to the list, fixed now. Thanks!!

Comment: @Zeorth when you say separate out the printing, it conveys the idea of criteria or grouping, the simplest solution would be to use an `if` statement. It might be better if you asked a separate question illustrating the requirement better

Comment: @Zeorth zaggler  seems to have given a detailed answer, can you please mark the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've come across the issue where I seem to be getting the error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Prog2Prov.Program+Order] when trying to print out the list

There are a few issue's I've found in the above code. First I'll address the actual issue.

```
 if (shipping == "t")
 {
    Console.WriteLine(orders);
 }
```

You're printing the string representation of your `List<Order>` which is `System.Collections.Generic.List1[Prog2Prov.Program+Order]`. Instead you need to print each `Order` in that list. As mentioned in my comments above you can do a simple `foreach` or `linq`:

Here's the `foreach`:

```
 foreach(var o in orders) 
    Console.WriteLine(o);
```

Here's `linq`:

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', orders.Select(o => o.ToString())));
```

Another option, if you don't want to do this, you can inherit the `List<T>` and `override` the `ToString` in your new class.

```
using System.Linq;

public class OrderList : List<Order>
{
   public override string ToString() => string.Join("\n", this.Select(o => o.ToString()));
}
```

Then you can use the new list:

```
 OrderList ol = new OrderList();
 ol.Add(new NormalOrder("order 1", 1, DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Nowhere Town"));
 ol.Add(new SpecialOrder("special order 2", 2, DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Nowhere Town 2"));
 MessageBox.Show(ol.ToString());
```

Here's my output from above:

[image]

Another issue I seen was:

```
 town.ToList();
```

As well as:

```
 country.ToList();
```

Both of these are defined as `string`, you'll still have an issue when printing them out, you need to remove the `ToList()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a discriminated union via [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) library.

```cs
var myList = new List<OneOf<SpecialOrder, NormalOrder>>()
{
    new NormalOrder(...), new SpecialOrder(...)
};
myList[0].Switch(
    special => Console.WriteLine("Special"),
    normal => Console.WriteLine("Normal"),
);
```

---

However, polymorphism is much better for this scenario

Comment: how does this answer the question regarding  `error System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Prog2Prov.Program+Order]`